# Как в VSC задействовать автозавершение по небуквенным символам?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Привык в VBA что после ввода точки (или скобки или кавычки и т.д.) выделенное слово в интелисенсе автоматически завершается. А как настроить подобное в VSC? Надоедает ВВОД/ТАБ нажимать, после которого снова надо точку ставить. Лишняя операция получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение найдено здесь: [KeyBindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37436446/visual-studio-code-intellisense-auto-complete-behaviour)